# P, NP Problem and Turing Machines

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines

My first question here, I think this will be an easy one.

As for definition:

NP:
NP is the set of decision problems solvable in polynomial time by a theoretical non-deterministic Turing machine. (wiki)

P:
P Contains all decision problems that can be solved by a deterministic Turing machine using a polynomial amount of computation time, or polynomial time. (wiki)

(a) I thought, that you can convert every Non-deterministic Turing machine into a equivalent deterministic Turing machine ?

I am not sure about that I know it is possible with NFA's to DFA's.

But if (a) is true, wouldn't that mean that P=NP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a non-deterministic Turing machine can be converted into an equivalent deterministic Turing machine, but it is not known that if a polynomial time non-deterministic Turing machine can be converted into an equivalent **polynomial time** deterministic Turing machine.

Note "equivalent" only means they accept the same language, it does not mean they run in the same time.

Comment: ahh ok, but if it were possible then it would mean that P=NP ?

Comment: @simplesystems Yes.